# Populating Spinner with data from database, using ArrayList and HashMap

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, spinner

I need help with populating Spinner, with values from the ArrayList.

ArrayList is populated by reading values from database table:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getStudents() {
    //Open connection to read only
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery =  "select * from " + TABLE_STUDENTS;

    //Student student = new Student();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> student = new HashMap<String, String>();
            student.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.KEY_ID)));
            student.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.KEY_name)));
            studentList.add(student);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return studentList;

}
```

So, I need how to fill Spinner, with selected values. I tried with things like:

```
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList =  mydb.getStudents();

            // and this is where I have the problem:
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, studentList);
```

Can you help me how to populate Spinner please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, studentList);
```

to create adapter for your spinner,notice that `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` is a layout in android system,it has a TextView on one row,so you can't give a list which type is `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` as data,to fix it,you can use `SimpleArrayAdapter` instead or use your custom Adapter by extends `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new class AdapterStudents that extends ArrayAdapter. Assuming that your layout for a spinner row contains two TextViews, i.e. txtViewId for student Id and txtViewName for Name, you could use the following code:

```
public class AdapterStudent extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList;

    public AdapterStudent(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, arrayCountries);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtViewId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtViewId);
            holder.txtViewNam = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtViewName);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtViewId.setText(studentList.get(i).get("id"));
        holder.txtViewName.setText(studentList.get(i).get("name"));

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewId;
        TextView txtViewName;
    }


}
```

From your main activity, which contains the spinner, you then need to call

```
Spinner spinnerStudents = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerlayoutname)
spinnerlayoutname.setAdapter(new AdapterStudent(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinnerrowlayoutid, studentList));
```

With this you should be set. Have adapted above from a running code in my app, happy to explain if you need more clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your adapter extending from CursorAdapter:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View rowView, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_layout_text_view); // This is your textview inside the layout that your spinner will use

        // Extract properties from cursor
        String studentName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Student.KEY_name));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        textView.setText(studentName);
    }
}
```

Then, when you initialize the spinner (onCreate on Activity)

```
// Get a reference from your Spinner
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);

// Get your cursor from a Db.
Cursor cursor = Get_Cursor_From_Db(); // Implement your logic and return a Cursor

// Create your adapter and tell it how is the cursor
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, cursor);

// Set the adapter to the Spinner.
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Using this way, you don't need to worry about this HashMap.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom adapter class for custom adapter item:
**CustomAdapter.java**

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context=context;
        this.studentList=studentList;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, parent,
                    false);
        // get your views here and set values to them

        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        HashMap<String, String> rowItem = studentList.get(position);

        String value = (String) rowItem.get(key);

        textview.setText(value);

        return row;
    }


    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, parent,
                        false);

        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        HashMap<String, String> rowItem = studentList.get(position);

        String value = (String) rowItem.get(key);

        textview.setText(value);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Create also a xml file.

**custom_spinner_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then use something like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList =  mydb.getStudents();

        // and this is where I have the problem:
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```